# DataBinding a WPF PropertyGrid in a "Visual Studio"-fashion

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

I'm creating a simply editor for a game using Fluent Ribbon and Avalon Dock, since the editor is highly specific I cannot share a direct screenshot, hence I'm using Visual Studio as an example:

[image: Visual Studio layout]

The idea is that every component that does so desire (be it something in a document or something from the Solution Explorer) can set an active object in the Properties for editing.

Right now I gave my properties window a `public object ActiveObject` and applied a singleton pattern so other components can access this. But it just feels awfully hacky and was therefor wondering: What would be a better way to go about this in a nice MVVM way? Or is the approach fine? Should I instead databind the properties window to a property on some shared singleton class? I really have no idea how to go about this other than I did.

Comment: You could use something like EventAggregator/Mediator pattern to "post" activeobject to the Properties window (or to it's view model).

Comment: Is it wrong to not want other windows to have knowledge of the properties window? It feels like tight coupling two independent components. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: No, it is not wrong to want independent components loosely coupled.